# An object binded with .click(function() {...}); has no effect on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, onclick

I'm trying to bind to a span element a function to scroll a slideshow (specifically rcarousel plugin). 
that's the javascript code:

```
$('.forward').click(function() {
    $("#carousel").rcarousel("next");
});

$('.rewind').click(function() {
    $("#carousel").rcarousel("goToPage", 0);
});
```

Now, this code is inside a document.ready function, the forward button $(".forward")  works and successfully scrolls the slideshow, but it's like the rewind button being totally ignored by the browser. With no errors thrown by the chrome devtools console; and if I paste the same code in the console .rewind starts magically to work.

Anyone knows what kind of sorcery is going on there?

PS: In the same document.ready function there are other bindings, each working flawlessly

Comment: Is that `rewind` button dynamically created, or do you have it in the source of your page?

Comment: Does `.rewind` exist when you bind the handler? All we can do now is guessing. If you provide a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo, you have better chances of getting a helpful answer (and it likely saves our and your time).

Comment: both rewind and forward are in the page source, but rewind is hidden or not displayed, because is in the second slide of the carousel.
Here the page: http://www.mlefrz.org/home/bwindex.html the forward object has the class "avanti" (forward in italian) and rewind has "torna" class and id (italian for rewind)

Comment: Add your answer below.

Comment: Try to add another code line like console.log("clicked"); to your function and test whether it works or not. If console writes that, that means there is problem with your rcarousel plugin.

Comment: i get a 404 at mlefrz.org/home/bwindex.html

Answer (score 1):

The carousel buttons are changed dynamically by the carousel, so you need to use a delegated event handler, attached to a non-changing ancestor (`document` is the default of nothing closer is handy):

```
$(document).on('click', '.forward', function() {
    $("#carousel").rcarousel("next");
});

$(document).on('click', '.rewind', function() {
    $("#carousel").rcarousel("goToPage", 0);
});
```

Delegated events work by listening for the event to bubble up to a non-changing ancestor, *then* applying the jQuery selector, *then* applying the function to any clicked elements *that  caused the event*. This means that the element only need to match at event time, not *event registration time).

Note: Do not connect delegated event handlers to `'body'` as styling can cause body to have a zero height and not respond to bubbled mouse events.